# Algorithm for finding all maximum out-trees in a digraph

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, trees

If we have a directed graph, and the graph contains subgraphs which are out-trees. We could find the set of out-trees, such that it does not contain any out-tree that is contained by another out-tree.

EDIT:
I am looking for an algorithm to calculate the set of these maximal out-trees for a given directed graph. I'm not sure if this is a problem that exists in graphs literature or not.

The number of trees may be high, but I may be able to combine trees after looking at an algorithm. I came up with an algorithm for a DAG. But I really need it for the more general case

Comment: Could you make it more clear what the _question_ you want answered is?

Comment: Do you want the actual trees enumerated (one at a time?) or is it enough to know how many there are? There can be quite a lot of them -- for a complete directed graph [Cayley's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley's_formula) gives superexponentially many.

Comment: I want to enumerate them. Here is the original question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1792290/enumerate-out-trees-that-include-a-set-of-nodes-in-a-directed-graph. And yes maybe I should have asked it first.