# Enumerate out-trees that include a set of nodes in a directed graph

Tags: graph-theory, trees

Given a digraph A, and an N set of nodes in the digraph. I need to enumerate the set of out-trees that contain those nodes. Where all the the out-trees leaves terminate on a node in set N.

EDIT:
I am now exploring options other than the one below. Also in my particular domain I don't need to enumerate a long list. I want a unique answer, but I do need to do an exhaustive search to make sure there is no second answer.

As a possible solution I am considering if finding the set T of all the maximum out-trees in the digraph A. Where the out-trees in T are not contained by any other out-tree in A. And I asked that [other question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1791881/algorithm-for-finding-all-maximum-out-trees-in-a-digraph). The idea was to have on each node a list of out-trees of which the node is a member. And I would just intersect that for all nodes. Then search for out-trees, inside the maximum out-trees. To keep the number of trees down I would collapse bifurcations in particular way that I don't think is necessary to go into here.

Comment: This sounds a lot like you're having an [X/Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) -- especially it looks like you haven't considered _just how absurdly many trees_ there can be in even a smallish graph. What is the _actual_ problem you need this for solving?

Comment: @HenningMakholm, I appreciate your comment. I am working on a query language extension, that would infer the tables used. Nodes represent tables, and arcs represent foreign keys. On a given query there would be some tables specified, but not all. Finding a unique tree would be the inference. It has to be unique otherwise there would be underspecified behavior. I'd like to know all the trees for error messages. Although It may be enough to find two trees or a unique tree.